# Has Boruto the anime caught up with the manga?

Tags: boruto

Did the *Boruto* anime catch up with the manga? If it did, can you tell me from which episode should I start watching *Boruto*?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably watch Boruto from the start. Though it happens in the movie but it still feels better when you watch from the start and it is also not that much. There are only just 68 episodes in total released until now. You can binge watch them in like 2 days.

Also, it is better if we do not compare anime and manga content when the anime is ahead of the manga as in case of DB Super and also Boruto as they may be very different and manga can give some content which is crucial for the story and the anime misses it as it is directed by some other person and not by the mangaka (for example we came to know in DB Super that if the kaioshin dies so does Beerus, it was told earlier in the manga while the anime had already gone much further from that point of the story, though the anime included that bit in the very next episode released after the chapter in which this info was provided).